# Call c function from Java

Tags: java, c

How to call c function from Java.
Seems c is compiler based.

I would like to call C  function in Windows from Java, and
GCC function fron Java too.

Any reference?

Comment: You may like to look at JNI(Java Native Interface).

Comment: asked May 11 '11 at 11:11 :-)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Have a look at [Java Native Interface: Getting Started](http://web.archive.org/web/20120419230023/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html).

> 2.1 Overview
>
> [...] write a simple Java application that calls a C function to print
>   "Hello World!". The process consists of the following steps:
>
> Create a class (HelloWorld.java) that declares the native method. Use
>   javac to compile the HelloWorld source file, resulting in the class
>   file HelloWorld.class. The javac compiler is supplied with JDK or Java
>   2 SDK releases. Use `javah -jni` to generate a C header file
>   (`HelloWorld.h`) containing the function prototype for the native method
>   implementation. The javah tool is provided with JDK or Java 2 SDK
>   releases. Write the C implementation (`HelloWorld.c`) of the native
>   method. Compile the C implementation into a native library, creating
>   `Hello-World.dll` or `libHello-World.so`. Use the C compiler and linker
>   available on the host environment. Run the HelloWorld program using
>   the java runtime interpreter. Both the class file (`HelloWorld.class`)
>   and the native library (`HelloWorld.dll` or `libHelloWorld.so`) are loaded
>   at runtime. The remainder of this chapter explains these steps in
>   detail.
>
> 2.2 Declare the Native Method
>
> You begin by writing the following program in the Java programming
>   language. The program defines a class named HelloWorld that contains a
>   native method, print.
>
> ```
> class HelloWorld {
>     private native void print();
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         new HelloWorld().print();
>     }
>
>     static {
>         System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The HelloWorld class definition begins with the declaration of the print native method. This is followed by a main method that
>   instantiates the Hello-World class and invokes the print native method
>   for this instance. The last part of the class definition is a static
>   initializer that loads the native library containing the
>   implementation of the print native method.
>
> There are two differences between the declaration of a native method
>   such as print and the declaration of regular methods in the Java
>   programming language. A native method declaration must contain the
>   native modifier. The native modifier indicates that this method is
>   implemented in another language. Also, the native method declaration
>   is terminated with a semicolon, the statement terminator symbol,
>   because there is no implementation for native methods in the class
>   itself. We will implement the print method in a separate C file.
>
> Before the native method print can be called, the native library that
>   implements print must be loaded. In this case, we load the native
>   library in the static initializer of the `HelloWorld` class. The Java
>   virtual machine automatically runs the static initializer before
>   invoking any methods in the `HelloWorld` class, thus ensuring that the
>   native library is loaded before the print native method is called.
>
> We define a main method to be able to run the `HelloWorld` class.
>   `Hello-World.main` calls the native method print in the same manner as
>   it would call a regular method.
>
> `System.loadLibrary` takes a library name, locates a native library that
>   corresponds to that name, and loads the native library into the
>   application. We will discuss the exact loading process later in the
>   book. For now simply remember that in order for
>   `System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld")` to succeed, we need to create a
>   native library called `HelloWorld.dll` on Win32, or `libHelloWorld.so` on
>   Solaris.
>
> 2.3 Compile the HelloWorld Class
>
> After you have defined the HelloWorld class, save the source code in a
>   file called HelloWorld.java. Then compile the source file using the
>   javac compiler that comes with the JDK or Java 2 SDK release:
>
> ```
>  javac HelloWorld.java
> ```
>
> This command will generate a `HelloWorld.class`
>   file in the current directory.
>
> 2.4 Create the Native Method Header File
>
> Next we will use the `javah` tool to generate a JNI-style header file
>   that is useful when implementing the native method in C. You can run
>   `javah` on the `Hello-World` class as follows:
>
> ```
>   javah -jni HelloWorld
> ```
>
> The name of the header file is the class name
>   with a "`.h`" appended to the end of it. The command shown above
>   generates a file named `HelloWorld.h`. We will not list the generated
>   header file in its entirety here. The most important part of the
>   header file is the function prototype for `Java_HelloWorld_print`, which
>   is the C function that implements the HelloWorld.print method:
>
> ```
>  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL   Java_HelloWorld_print (JNIEnv *, jobject);
> ```
>
> Ignore the `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` macros for now. You may have noticed
>   that the C implementation of the native method accepts two arguments
>   even though the corresponding declaration of the native method accepts
>   no arguments. The first argument for every native method
>   implementation is a `JNIEnv` interface pointer. The second argument is a
>   reference to the `HelloWorld` object itself (sort of like the "`this`"
>   pointer in C++). We will discuss how to use the `JNIEnv` interface
>   pointer and the `jobject` arguments later in this book, but this simple
>   example ignores both arguments.
>
> 2.5 Write the Native Method Implementation
>
> The JNI-style header file generated by `javah` helps you to write C or
>   C++ implementations for the native method. The function that you write
>   must follow the -prototype specified in the generated header file. You
>   can implement the `Hello-World.print` method in a C file `HelloWorld.c` as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> #include <jni.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include "HelloWorld.h"   
>
> JNIEXPORT void JNICALL   Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)  {
>      printf("Hello World!\n");
>      return;
> }
> ```
>
> The implementation of this native method is straightforward. It uses the printf function to display the string "Hello World!" and then returns. As mentioned before, both arguments, the `JNIEnv` pointer and the reference to the object, are ignored.
>
> The C program includes three header files:
>
> `jni.h` -- This header file provides information the native code needs
>   to call JNI functions. When writing native methods, you must always
>   include this file in your C or C++ source files. 
>   `stdio.h` -- The code
>   snippet above also includes `stdio.h` because it uses the `printf`
>   function.
>   `HelloWorld.h` -- The header file that you generated using
>   `javah`. It includes the C/C++ prototype for the `Java_HelloWorld_print`
>   function.
>   2.6 Compile the C Source and Create a Native Library
>
> Remember that when you created the `HelloWorld` class in the
>   `HelloWorld.java` file, you included a line of code that loaded a native
>   library into the program:
>
> ```
>  System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
> ```
>
> Now that all the necessary C code
>   is written, you need to compile `Hello-World.c` and build this native
>   library.
>
> Different operating systems support different ways to build native
>   libraries. On Solaris, the following command builds a shared library
>   called libHello-World.so:
>
> ```
>  cc -G -I/java/include -I/java/include/solaris HelloWorld.c -o libHelloWorld.so
> ```
>
> The -G option instructs the C compiler to generate a shared library instead of a regular Solaris
>   executable file. Because of the limitation of page width in this book,
>   we break the command line into two lines. You need to type the command
>   in a single line, or place the command in a script file. On `Win32`, the
>   following command builds a dynamic link library (DLL) `HelloWorld.dll`
>   using the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler:
>
> ```
>  cl -Ic:\java\include -Ic:\java\include\win32 -MD -LD HelloWorld.c -FeHelloWorld.dll
> ```
>
> The `-MD` option ensures that `HelloWorld.dll` is linked with the `Win32` multithreaded C library.
>   The `-LD` option instructs the C compiler to generate a DLL instead of a
>   regular Win32 executable. Of course, on both Solaris and Win32 you
>   need to put in the include paths that reflect the setup on your own
>   machine.
>
> 2.7 Run the Program
>
> At this point, you have the two components ready to run the program.
>   The class file (`HelloWorld.class`) calls a native method, and the
>   native library (`Hello-World.dll`) implements the native method.
>
> Because the `HelloWorld` class contains its own main method, you can run
>   the program on Solaris or Win32 as follows:
>
> ```
>  java HelloWorld
> ```
>
> You should see the following output:
>
> ```
>    Hello World!
> ```
>
> It is important to set your native library path
>   correctly for your program to run. The native library path is a list
>   of directories that the Java virtual machine searches when loading
>   native libraries. If you do not have a native library path set up
>   correctly, then you see an error similar to the following:
>
> ```
>  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HelloWorld in library path
>          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java)
>          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java)
>          at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java)
> ```
>
> Make sure that the native library resides in one of the directories in the native library path.
>   If you are running on a Solaris system, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
>   environment variable is used to define the native library path. Make
>   sure that it includes the name of the directory that contains the
>   `libHelloWorld.so` file. If the `libHelloWorld.so` file is in the current
>   directory, you can issue the following two commands in the standard
>   shell (sh) or KornShell (ksh) to set up the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
>   environment variable properly:
>
> ```
>  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
>  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> ```
>
> The equivalent command in
>   the C shell (csh or tcsh) is as follows:
>
> ```
>  setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .
> ```
>
> If you are running on a Windows 95 or
>   Windows NT machine, make sure that `HelloWorld.dll` is in the current
>   directory, or in a directory that is listed in the PATH environment
>   variable.
>
> In Java 2 SDK 1.2 release, you can also specify the native library
>   path on the java command line as a system property as follows:
>
> ```
>  java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
> ```
>
> The "`-D`" command-line option
>   sets a Java platform system property. Setting the `java.library.path`
>   property to "`.`" instructs the Java virtual machine to search for
>   native libraries in the current directory.

Comment: Mac users can disregard solaris commands. This blog helped me finish what this answer helped start: http://nerdposts.blogspot.com/2010/10/jni-mac-os-x-simple-sample.html

Comment: People this would also come handy while reading this and frustrating why javah is not working and telling you `Error: Could not find class file for 'YourFileName.class'.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137201/javah-tool-error-could-not-find-class-file-for-hellojni

Comment: For Java >= 9 javah is deprecated so use ```javac -h . HelloWorld.java```. This is answered all over the place but ill add it here just for tl;dr.

Answer (score 12):

In simple terms, just make sure you load the relevant library which contains the function definition, load the library which follows the JNI specification and wraps the target function from the first library, expose native methods from your Java class and you should be good to go.

I'd recommend against raw JNI since it contains a lot of boilerplate code and you would end up cursing yourself if you start wrapping a *big* C library. By all means do feel free to dabble in JNI when starting out but use something like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) when it comes to real work.

Comment: Is JNA as fast as JNI?

Answer (score 5):

You options include:

**Java Native Interface** 
see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

quote:

> JNI enables programmers to write native methods to handle situations when an application cannot be written entirely in the Java programming language, e.g. when the standard Java class library does not support the platform-specific features or program library

**Java Native Access**

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access

quote:

> Java Native Access is a community-developed library that provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries without using the Java Native Interface.

**JNR-FFI**

see: https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi

quote:

> jnr-ffi is a java library for loading native libraries without writing JNI code by hand, or using tools such as SWIG.

Comment: So JNR diff JNA is?

Answer (score 3):

In the "exotic" category, see NestedVM, which compiles the C to Mips, and runs a Mips
VM inside JVM.

http://nestedvm.ibex.org/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout  JNAerator.
https://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/

You need to provide the source code and preprocessor definitions etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows and MinGW gcc you may need additional flag if you are getting UnsatisfiedLinkError for specific method in lib:

```
gcc -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at -I"%JAVA_HOME%"\include -I"%JAVA_HOME%"\include\win32 BestCode.c -shared -o BestCode.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas) gave a very elaborated answer, but I think its also  really worth checking this website and you will get all your essential answers there :

**http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javanativeinterface.html**

It explains how to call a program using JNI  :

- For languages C and C++ or a mixture of both
- JNI without any parameters, primitives, strings or Array of primitives
- Accessing object variables, callback instances methods and much more.

Comment: the web page is down , the new link is https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/ehchua/programming/java/javanativeinterface.html

Answer (score 0):

For making 64-bit compatible dll Remove "-MD" option from statement below

```
cl -Ic:\java\include -Ic:\java\include\win32 -MD -LD HelloWorld.c -FeHelloWorld.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this problem.  What you need to ensure is you're compiling the code using 64-bit c++ compiler for calling java function running on 64-bit JRE. Along with it we need to save the path of created dll file in "Path" under "Environment variable".

Answer (score 0):

First make ensure to load your native library or .dll file in class path by setting path at property `java.library.path`

Then use `System.loadLibrary()`

```
Do not use .dll extension at the end.
```