# Javah tool error: Could not find class file for hellojni

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javah

I am trying to create a header file using javah tool from command line on windows 7 OS but i am failing all the time.

I have followed different ways and even read the documentation of javah tool from oracle but they didn't help to overcome with this problem.

My class file (`hellojni.class`) and java file (`hellojni.java`) both are in the root of `D:\` drive.

But whenever I run javah tool it gives me an error:

> could not find class file for hellojni

I tried by providing classpath as well but not getting any header file.

Comment: Can you add the exact command you're running?

Comment: Yea. It is d:\>javah -classpath d:\ hellojni

Comment: see @hendalst 's answer if anyone new finding solution here

Answer (score 115):

I suspect the issue is that **your class has a package and you are trying to run the command from the directory with the class file instead of the package root**.

Samhain's example works because his `MyClass.java` contains no package, whereas I suspect yours does.

For example, assume we have the following file at `c:\src\com\example\MyClass.java`

```
package com.example;

public class MyClass {
    public native void myMethod();
}
```

Go to the command line and execute the following:

```
c:\src\com\example>javac MyClass.java

c:\src\com\example>dir

 Directory of C:\src\com\example

2015-02-23  03:17 PM    <DIR>          .
2015-02-23  03:17 PM    <DIR>          ..
2015-02-23  03:20 PM               219 MyClass.class
2015-02-23  03:17 PM                84 MyClass.java

c:\src\com\example>javah MyClass
Error: Could not find class file for 'MyClass'.

c:\src\com\example>cd c:\src

c:\src>javah com.example.MyClass

c:\src>dir
 Directory of C:\src

2015-02-23  03:18 PM    <DIR>          .
2015-02-23  03:18 PM    <DIR>          ..
2015-02-23  03:16 PM    <DIR>          com
2015-02-23  03:18 PM               449 com_example_MyClass.h
```

Success!

Comment: thanks so much... saved my lot of hours... hence upvote... love u man!!!... u rock man!!!

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the hint. Classic problem when transitioning from simple academic setups for testing the JNI directly, to integrating it into the actual product, where packages and stuff suddenly are important.

Comment: Repeating the exact steps with the same MyClass file in 8_45 fails with the same error.

Comment: oh man Thank you this worked smooth as silk! I was getting so pissed of that it was not possible to compile

Answer (score 17):

I also faced the same problem when trying to compile and generate the C/C++ header in two steps for a Java Native Interface (JNI) implementation (I suspect that is what your trying to do from the file names). What solved it for me was to merge the two steps into one using the following command:

```
javac YOUR_CLASS_FILE_NAME.java -h .
```

The dot (.) includes the current path. This command can only be run as of Java 8.

Comment: Guys, make note of dot (.). I was missing dot(.).  Thanks for pointing out. Saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 7):

`javah -classpath path_to_jars_or_classes com.my.package.MyClass`.

If you run with -verbose, `javah -verbose -classpath path_to_jars_or_classes com.my.package.MyClass`, it will show you the Search Path that it is using to locate your classes.  You can use that to validate if your directory, D:\, is listed.

See [javah Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html)

Example:
  File is named MyClass.java, internal class name is MyClass.  No errors.

```
C:\>more MyClass.java
public class MyClass
{
   public static void doSomething(int b)
   {
      return;
   }
}

C:\>javac MyClass.java

C:\>javah -classpath C:\ MyClass

C:\>dir *.h
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\

10/07/2013  11:46 AM               242 MyClass.h
               1 File(s)            242 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  X bytes free
```

Comment: Thank you Samhain for yours reply. According to yours reply the command i have tried is **d:\>javah -verbose -classpath d:\ hellojni**. But still got the same error. Actually my class file and java file both are in the root of 'd' drive so i think i can't do like **com.my.package.myclass**. If possible could you post the exact command please. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried the way you posted. But still it is giving me a same error. If it is possible i can send you the screenshot as well. Is it possible we can make check where **javah** is looking for class files.

Comment: @S.SSahota post a listing of the files present on your D:\, a small sample of your .java file(mainly the class declaration), and the output from javah with -verbose.

Comment: I have got some other directories but files are **HelloJNI.class** and **HelloJNI.java**. The code in **HelloJNI.java** is `public class HelloJNI
{

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello");
    }
   
    private native void sayHello();
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new HelloJNI().sayHello();
    }
}` When i tried **javah -verbose hellojni** i got the same error. When i tried **javah -verbose -classpath d:\ hellojni** i got the same error.

Comment: @S.SSahota Your classname is HelloJNI, not hellojni.  The commandis case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much Samhain. it did work and i am surprised it is case sensitive command. **javah** documentation should mention this point.

Comment: that verbose thing didnt work in my case. With or without verbose, the error message is exact same. Wasted my time :(

Answer (score 4):

I had such problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with Java 8 and Java 11 installed (and default):

```
$ javac -cp target/classes -d target/classes src/main/java/jni/JNIClass.java
$ javah -cp target/classes -d lib/ jni.JNIClass
Error: Could not find class file for 'jtni.JNIClass'.
```

It appeared, that javac was pointing to Java 11 implementation, but javah still pointed to Java 8, because [javah is not included in Java 11 anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352098/javah-missing-after-jdk-install).

Solution for Java 11 is to use javac and request it to generate header file:

```
$ javac -cp target/classes -h lib/ src/main/java/jni/JNIClass.java
```

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your class file is in D:/A folder
cd your command prompt to folder A and run below command

D:/A>javah -classpath . classfilename

Here `.` will set the classpath to current directory and javah tool should be able to find your class file.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS X, it required the classpath variable. This might be the solution if it can be verified on other platforms as well.

```
$ javah -verbose Article.HelloJNICpp
$ javah -verbose -classpath ./ Article.HelloJNICpp
[Creating file RegularFileObject[Article_HelloJNICpp.h]]
$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse:
append -classpath PATH_OF_PACKAGE_TOP into javah CLASSNAME

Example:`javah -classpath . com.byf.test.JNI`

```
my tree : `
.
├── com
│   └── byf
│       └── test
│           └── JNI.java
└── libcall.so`


result:`
    byf@byf-Ubuntu:~/code/workspace_eclipse_java/JAVA_YF/src$ javah -classpath . com.byf.test.JNI
    byf@byf-Ubuntu:~/code/workspace_eclipse_java/JAVA_YF/src$ ls
    com  com_byf_test_JNI.h  libcall.so
    byf@byf-Ubuntu:~/code/workspace_eclipse_java/JAVA_YF/src$ cat com_byf_test_JNI.h 
    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include <jni.h>
    /* Header for class com_byf_test_JNI */

    #ifndef _Included_com_byf_test_JNI
    #define _Included_com_byf_test_JNI
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    /*
     * Class:     com_byf_test_JNI
     * Method:    add
     * Signature: (II)I
     */
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_byf_test_JNI_add
      (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint, jint);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    #endif
    `
```