# Generating Java header file error

Tags: java, cmd, java-native-interface

Sorry for asking but I am having trouble generating a Java header file from my code - in command prompt I typed:

```
javah -o JNIDemoJava.h -classpath JNIDemoJava/build/classes jnidemojava.Main
```

From what I've read that should have worked but I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find class file for 'jnidemojava.Main'.
```

Before you say I forgot to clean and build to compile it I did, but I still have this error if you need more info just ask .

Update: Problem was solved

Comment: What does this have to do with C++ or C languages (per your tags)?

Comment: i was going to make a jni project that uses C++ and C code so i thought of adding the tags. if u want i can remove the tags

Comment: Is you class called `jnidemojava.Main`, or is it really called `jnidemojava`? Have a look at [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19161596/622391) - you may find it helpful.

Comment: the class name is Main and my source package is called jnidemojava. i just followed this https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html as a example and cant get the header file

Comment: Does the file `JNIDemoJava/build/classes/jnidemojava/Main.class` exist? The evidence says not.

Comment: yes  the file exists

Comment: Does the directory `./JNIDemoJava` exist in the current directory when you execute this command? The evidence says not.

Comment: i solved it i feel so stupid now but thanks for all the help it worked thanks EJP

Comment: Solved it how? If you're not going to tell us, the question has no permanent value here and should be deleted.

Comment: its exactly what you said above i checked and the folder didnt exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your command is right. In which platform you run your command? Be cautious to the file separator, it's `\` in Windows and `/` in *NIX.

So in Windows you should

```
javah -o JNIDemoJava.h -classpath JNIDemoJava\build\classes jnidemojava.Main
```

In *NIX, you should

```
javah -o JNIDemoJava.h -classpath JNIDemoJava/build/classes jnidemojava.Main
```