# javah missing after JDK install

Tags: java, javah

I can find `java`, `javac` and `javadoc` but there is no `javah.exe` in my `jdk\\bin` folder.

I tried to reinstall the JDK but it is still missing. How can I get it, why is it missing?

I found a similar question where the operating system was Linux but I can not find answers for Windows users.

My OS is Windows *10*. The Java version is *10.0.1*.

Comment: According to [JEP 313](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/313) `javah` has been removed from the JDK since Java 10. *Users have been warned of the pending removal since JDK 9, in which a warning is generated each time the javah tool is invoked.*

Answer (score 19):

The tool `javah.exe` was **removed** in Java 10. The reason is simple, it is obsolete. From [JEP 313: Remove the Native-header Generation Tool (javah)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/313):

> **Motivation**
>
> The tool has been superseded by superior functionality in `javac`, added in **JDK 8** ([JDK-7150368](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7150368)). This functionality provides the ability to write native header files at the time that Java source code is compiled, thereby **eliminating the need for a separate tool**.
>
> Focusing on the support provided by `javac` eliminates the need to upgrade `javah` to support recent new paradigms, such as API access via the Compiler API in `javax.tools.*`, or the new `java.util.spi.ToolProvider` SPI added in *JDK 9*.

So you can just use `javac.exe` if you are on Java 8 or newer.

Comment: Yes. Like this: 
"javac /home/user/Foobar.java -h /home/user/"
And the .h file will be generated at "/home/user" on Linux.

Answer (score 18):

`javah` has been superseded by the `-h` option added to `javac` in JDK 8.

It is deprecated since Java 9.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javah.htm) for details.