# javah 'Could not find class file' for mulitple paths

Tags: java, javah

I have a class file with a native method on a path while its dependencies live on a separate path in a different package. My tree looks something like:

```
[build/classes]$ tree -L 3    
.
├── main
│   └── com
│       └── foo
└── test
    └── com
        └── foo
```

My dependencies live on the main path while the class file I'm trying to build the header for is on the test path. The files look something like:

```
// FooTest.java: class file will go to build/classes/test/com/foo/
package com.foo;    
import com.foo.bar.Depend;
public class FooTest { 
  private native void baz(int i);
  public FooTest() {
    Depend depend = new Depend();
    baz(depend.get());
  }
}

// Depend.java: class file will go to build/classes/main/com/foo/bar
package com.foo.bar;
public class Depend {
  public int get() { return 3; }
}
```

Now back to the `build/classes` dir. Let's invoke our javah command:

```
[build/classes]$ javah -classpath "test/" com.foo.FooTest
Error: Class com.foo.bar.Depend could not be found.
```

Darn. It couldn't find the dependency. Shouldn't be surprised: it's not on the path! We'll use classpath separator `;` to send multiple searchpaths.

```
[build/classes]$ javah -classpath "test/;main/" com.foo.FooTest
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.foo.FooTest'.
```

What? It can't find the class file in the `test` dir now. Flip the order of the paths? Turn on verbose? Write the full path?

```
[build/classes]$ javah -verbose -classpath "main/;test/" com.foo.FooTest
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.foo.FooTest'.
[build/classes]$ javah -verbose -classpath "/the_full_path/main/;/the_full_path/test/" com.foo.FooTest
Error: Could not find class file for 'com.foo.FooTest'.
```

Blast! I tried all the combinations! Verbose gives me nothing and I'm getting the same error. I've read quite a few of the similar questions including [this highly voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28668774/2183336) but have not found a solution that works for me.

Comment: you have to include all the paths with compiled classes/jars in classpath

Comment: I suggest using a build tool like maven

Comment: @user85421 you're right. I think that should be so. I really thought that may work but using `:` yields the same error. I even tried exporting the fullpath to `CLASSPATH` without any luck. @LazarPetrovic I'm using gradle.