# How to access a C method in java application..?

Tags: java, c

it is a simple question how can i access a method which is written in C language by a java application.

Comment: JNI is what you're looking for.

Comment: using pointer in c program now i want to access this c program in my java application,

Comment: "its a simple question" -> exactly, so it is already asked numerous times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963266/call-c-function-from-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You options include:

**Java Native Interface** 
see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

quote:

> JNI enables programmers to write native methods to handle situations when an application cannot be written entirely in the Java programming language, e.g. when the standard Java class library does not support the platform-specific features or program library

**Java Native Access**

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access

quote:

> Java Native Access is a community-developed library that provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries without using the Java Native Interface.

**JNR-FFI**

see: https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi

quote:

> jnr-ffi is a java library for loading native libraries without writing JNI code by hand, or using tools such as SWIG.

Comment: JNA and JNR-FFI are two alternatives.

Comment: @PeterLawrey isn't JNA the [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) for java?

Comment: Good point, it should be JNR-FFI.

Comment: I have added it to the answer