# Calling C files from web service

Tags: java, spring, apache

We are creating a web service in java using APACHE CXF framework, and from here we need to call few .c files which contains nothing but the methods for the db entry.

How can we call these .c files from our web service so that we can compile it and use the existing function for the db entry?

Comment: JNI(Java Native Interface)

Comment: Check the SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963266/call-c-function-from-java

Comment: Since it's just C, you could also look at JNA (Java Native Access) or JNR (Java Native Runtime) (Although the latter is far less used), which will more or less automatically bind the C code to Java, without having to define a JNI wrapper.

Comment: JNI - tutorial here http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html