# Building a project with multiple languages

Tags: java, c, eclipse, multiple-languages

I am trying to build a project in Eclipse (Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)) and am trying to use Java and C. I'm not asking how to code in either language, but I'm not sure how to call a C main function passing it a param from a Java class or function. I know projects are made from multiple languages but I'm not sure how it's done and I haven't found a very solid answer from Google.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused here.  Why are you talking about a C main function?  Is your question about calling any C function from Java and it just happens that the function you're trying to call is named `main`?  Or do you have a standalone app written in C and want to invoke it from Java?

Comment: I have an app that's basically a single function that needs to be written in C rather than Java. I wrote the function and call it from a `main` C function.

Comment: You can call, from Java, the C `main` function or that single function you call from `main`.  To do this you can use JNI, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963266/call-c-function-from-java.  Alternatively, you can build your C app and then invoke it from Java as an external process, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604698/java-programming-call-an-exe-from-java-and-passing-parameters.