# Run C code in android app (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-studio

I need to develop an Android application and use in it an algorithm that is written in C.
I found a lot of tutorials for running **ONE** C function from a java activity. But what I need is:

1) reading a string in a java activity and "sending" it to C/C++ (this part works).

2) starting a little C algo (it is written only in C. I mean from the moment that my algorithm starts I need to call other C functions that are in another C file).
This algo creates a new string (precisely char*).

3) returning this new string to the java activity (this part works).

My big problem is the second point.
Is there a special way to run an internal (with C functions calls) C code in Android? Special syntax?

I really hope someone here can help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963266/call-c-function-from-java https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it explains how to call c/c++ functions from Java. This part already works for me. My problem is to call C functions from others C functions in my app. For example, **inside** the first c function that prints "hello world", calling a second C function that prints "I'm fine". The whole algorithm I need is written in C. That's the reason. Anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: you should be able to call the second c function from the first, just by including a declaration of the second c function in the first c function; https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/51292 like: extern int foo(int,char);

Comment: or maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Android development but maybe [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/#samples) is what you may need ?

Comment: Yes but running c from Java already works for me. That's not my problem. But thank you very much for your answer!