# Call C function when Java object is about to be finalized/terminated (in SWIG)

Tags: java, swig

I have a Java object (created from a Java class generated by SWIG) that when it is about to terminate/finalize, I would like to call a C function to release some allocated resources by the C side of my program.

Basically, I would like to know how to extend the following Java method (generated by SWIG) with a call to a C function to release resources:

```
public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
        if (swigCMemOwn) {
            swigCMemOwn = false;
            TestJNI.delete_Pool(swigCPtr);

            TestJNI.releaseResource(swigCPtr);   // call C function to release resources

        }
        swigCPtr = 0;
    }
}
```

Could you please tell how to update the SWIG interface file so that it can include the line (with a comment) when generating the Java wrapper?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Library.html#Library_nn11) what you need ?

Comment: Thanks! It's more than I need to call a C function from inside the Java `delete` method though.

Comment: @user7698505 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963294/14475852).